# Map JS ArrayBuffer To .Net Type

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I'm trying to do a very simple thing (at least I think so): I want to upload some byte array (read from file most of the time) with some description (just a string) to my ASP.NET website, I also use TypeScript and AngularJS for it, but I don't think they are important here. So my JS code is as follows (simplified):

```
 var fileReader = new FileReader();
 fileReader.onloadend = eventData => {
     newItem.Title = "test";
     newItem.FileData = new Int8Array(fileReader.result); //???
     //$http posting newItem to service 
 };
 fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileElement.files[0]); //read from <input type='file'>
```

And my Web API method has this signature:

```
 public void Create(Item newItem)
```

With the following `Item` class:

```
    public class Item {
      public string Title { get; set; } //this is mapped correctly
      public byte[] FileData { get; set; } //???
    }
```

However, `FileData` is always `null` while `Title` is valid. Is it possible to do what I want? If so, how should I change code marked with `???` (or any other)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get `Int8Array` auto-mapped to `byte[]`. You'll have to deal with some kind of encoding/decoding and this is the right thing to do for the best management of speed and traffic. But if you really want to get "one array mapped to the other with minimum efforts" for small amounts of data, than you can use `int[]` on the server side and a regular array in your JS (`number[]` in TS)